# Eclipse Dynamic Web Project structure

Tags: java, eclipse, web

I'm working from Eclipse to generate my first Dynamic Web Project, but when I create it this structure appears to me:

[image: 1]

instead in all the tutorials that I have seen this type of structure appears:

[image: 2]

Why does it do this, is it a problem?
How can this be solved?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a real problem. The defaults in the Dynamic Web Project wizard [changed](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/releases/3.21/NewAndNoteworthy/#Modernized%20default%20paths). You can still enter `WebContent` into the **Content directory** field of the **Web Module** wizard page if you want the old behavior.

[image: The image from the New and Noteworthy]

Answer (score 0):

This structuring issue will be resolved in the later version of eclipse.Example: In Eclipse 2018 or later versions