# Eclipse Java Resources Folder

Tags: java, eclipse

I am learning Java Dynamic Web Development and have confusion about the folder structure created by Eclipse.  I am running the latest Eclipse IDE 2021-03 JEE and noticing that, when creating new projects, the project structure appears to be different when comparing to the online tutorials I've seen.  I am noticing a WebContent folder in which I believe I can simply rename the folder from "src/main/webapp" to "WebContent" in the Content Directory during the web project creation.  But the Java Resources is one that I cannot seem to add manually and it is always appearing in every tutorial I've seen.  I am hoping for some direction on this.

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66822939/eclipse-dynamic-web-project-structure . Don't worry about it being missing, it's not important.