# Eclipse /Java> my new Dynamic Web Project has src folder instead of WebContent folder

Tags: eclipse, setup-project

how can i make new project with WebContent folder not src folder

[nnn is new Dynamic Web Project ..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYmVK.jpg)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66822939/eclipse-dynamic-web-project-structure/66824890#66824890 .

Comment: @nitind Awesome!  You made my day.